# OnClickEvents Custom Listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

how to handle onclick events on a custom listrow?Is handling the event on the adapter the only/best option?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to click on different items in a list row, it's better to define different onClickListener on views in one row, otherwise it should be better to use onItemClickListener

Comment: yep thats it, but I have to do it in the getView of the adapter right?

Comment: i used to pass listeners to adapter, and set listener to views in getView for each row

Comment: pass listener to adapter?sorry i misunderstood that part

Comment: what i mean is that you can define listener in adapter directly, however, sometimes adapter doesn't have enough data, so it should be passed in from other classes such as activity

Answer (score 1):

You should `override`  `OnListItemClick`:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
}
```

the `position` parameter is holding the position of the `Object` inside your `Adapter`. So you can use it on order to retrieve it and make your computations.

Comment: But for example, iam trying to handle a click on an imageview in a listrow(which has several other widgets). position returns the position of the listview, not something i can use as a reference for the imageview

Comment: yes you are right. if you need a more granular control you should add an onClickLister on every view you need to manage touches. In order to do this you should have your own adapter

Answer (score 1):

You can use onItemClickListener for your ListView object, beware though, if you have focusable objects in your list items(edittext,button..) then this listener won't be notified anymore due to those objects. If you want to pass a reference of the listener to your adapter you should pass it as a weak reference.